# how to give column equal width from total width?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to make example of grid view .I am dynamically generate the table view or grid view .I need column take equal % of width .Example if I have two column they will take 50% with individual .If there is three column then they will take 33.33% individual

Please check image of grid what I am trying to make

![enter image description here][1]

Here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/X0PQov1UA2yEbx8qaOFl?p=preview

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{checked: true}">
        <div class="col">{{d.label}}</div>
        <div class="row" ng-repeat="column in displayData">
            <div class="col" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="d.fieldNameOrPath==field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BilalAkil but I am using ionic with angular .if you see my logic is complex

Comment: @BilalAkil could yoy please help in plunker I have two columns dynamically generated can we give both 50% width

Comment: @BilalAkil, the control being used is an Ionic control. And resulting markup is `div` not `table`. So unfortunately the proposed post cannot be applied

Comment: Fair enough, I'll remove my previous comment and try to come up with something for you.

Comment: Also note that the columns in the image you've provided have different widths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've got `display: flex` (and nothing about wrapping rows) on the containing element, it should work fine if you simply specify `width: 100%` on each column's `<div>`.

I've adjusted your Plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YAWmKBsgyevoyrhqfQqO?p=preview - the difference is the `style` attribute on this element:

```
<div style="width: 100%;" ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{checked: true}">...</div>
```

You can learn more about `display: flex` here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I recommend you also review your classes, since the current structure is quite confusing.