# how to use filter on button click in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to sort array in ascending or descending order on button click .Actually I have a button on header "V" .using button click I want to display data in ascending order .Actually I am making a grid view in Ionic using angular js .But I want to sort that using button click .I need to sort table according to first column .Because user click on first column "V".

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/UloVItuyLLvmeo34R4gX?p=preview

**Expected result after button click**

```
Calls   Royal Dutch sell

p        a royal data

Xgtyu     test royal data
```

can we sort the column and display on view on button click ?

```
  <div class="row gray-20 mrginrightleft">
    <div class="col col-center " ng-repeat="d in data | filter:{checked: true}"><i class="button button-icon icon ion-arrow-down-b" ng-click="sortdata()"></i><strong>{{d.label}}</strong></div>
    <div class="col col-10 text-center ">
      <button class=" button-icon icon ion-gear-b" ng-click="openPopover($event)"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mrginrightleft" ng-repeat="column in displayData | filter: query">
    <div class="col col-center brd" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="data[$index].checked && data[$index].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
    <div class="col col-10 text-center brd">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: Sort both directions**

### [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aGAI6EmCwGyPKmFZAFb8?p=preview)

To be able to sort in both directions, you should probably use a directive.  Using a directive will allow you to create an isolated scope for each of the headings, this way they can keep track of their own current values.

```
.directive('sortHeader', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'label': '@',
      'sortstring': '&sortExp',
      'idx': '@index'
    },
    templateUrl: 'sort-header.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.reverse = false;
      element.on('click', function(){
        $timeout(function(){
          scope.reverse = !scope.reverse;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

This directive has properties for:

1. `label` [*string*] The column header name.
2. `index` [*string*] The column index **in the original data set**.  Note, you cannot use the $index of the ng-repeat.
3. `sort-exp` [*method*]  This is a bindable method that you can use to retrieve the current index and reverse values to set your orderBy filter expression.  The function passes two values: `idx, reverse`, in that order.  These represent the index of the current element and reverse order as a *boolean*.

You use the directive as follows:

```
<sort-header label="{{d.label}}" index="{{d.index}}" sort-exp="setSort(idx, reverse)"></sort-header>
```

And, in your controller, you can bind to the sort-exp with a function:

```
$scope.setSort = function(idx, reverse){
  $scope.sortval = 'columns['+idx+'].value';
  $scope.reverse = reverse;
};
```

Finally, in your ng-repeat, you can set up your orderBy filter with the scope values that you used to define the sort expression (in this case $scope.sortval) and the sort order (in this case $scope.reverse):

```
ng-repeat="column in displayData | orderBy: sortval:reverse | filter: query"
```

Comment: Hi sir I have one Question ..can we toggle in between "ascending" and "descending"  on same button click .in other words on button click we display in ascending order . Now I need to display on descending order on same button click

Comment: I updated the Plunker and my answer.  There was a major error in my previous approach, which was that I was relying on the $index value of the ng-repeat.  This, of course, is flawed when you have hidden columns, because the index of the column in the repeat will not match that of the index of its corresponding object in your displayData.   I fixed this by transforming the data object to add a fixed index property to each object.

Comment: could you please see my last question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647801/how-to-reduce-the-height-of-header-in-tabel-view-or-grid-view

Answer (score 2):

if your `data` is an array then you can use orderBy filter
See official doc here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: yes I know this from this link but it I have nested array please check my plunker ..please check this displayData object

Comment: actually i am display data by using two object data  and displayData  .That why I am facing from to sort my column

Comment: @aorfeve do you have any idea .can another array and fill all collumn data

Comment: please remove this answer if you don't know the answer because it is not correect answer