# how to show only 25 element at one time?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying make table view in ionic using angular js .but I have lot of data to show around **5000 object** .So after getting data my UI hang because it is printing the data on dom.So I want to implement lazy loading so that only 100 element is visible to me or only 100 element present in dom only .When user scroll it download another 100 objects or element and removing the uppers element so that my UI not hang .can we do in angular js 
I will show you how my UI hang .take a look my example here

my loader hang for around 5 seconds ..

So I tried with infinite scroll in my demo so that I am able to show only 100 element at one time

here is my code of infinite scroll But I am not able to display 100 element at one time I didnot get any error also

```
  <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="canWeLoadMoreContent()" distance="10%">
      <div class="row" ng-repeat="column in _list | orderBy: sortval:reverse | filter: query">
        <div class="col col-center brd collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="invoice_column_name['index'].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
        <div class="col col-10 text-center brd collapse-sm"></div>
      </div>
      </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/18cGpCECrKuKIM4KkGfy?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/18cGpCECrKuKIM4KkGfy?p=preview)

I took a little different approach then the others.

There is a variable at the top of the controller called showitems.  This controls how many items you want to show at a time.  The counter variable will keep track of where how many items are shown.  Initially, the value is set to the showitems value since we're going to prepopulate the dataset with the first items immediately in the ShowViewAfterSuccess function.

```
var showitems = 100;
var counter = showitems;
```

In your ShowViewAfterSuccess function, I added the data to a scope variable called $scope.total_invoice_records.

Next, I run the first array slice on the data. This will pass the first x number of records to the $scope.invoice_records based on the value set in the showitems variable.  This initializes the view with the first set of records.

```
$scope.total_invoice_records=data.records;
$scope.invoice_records = $scope.total_invoice_records.slice(0, showitems);
```

I added a loadMore function that simply grabs the next x number of records from the total record set and concatenates them to the current set in $scope.invoice_records and increments the counter. loadMore will also check if there are still more records to load and broadcasts the message to the ionic infinite scroll directive to remove the spinner.

```
  $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = false;
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    var next = $scope.total_invoice_records.slice(counter, counter+showitems);
    $scope.invoice_records = $scope.invoice_records.concat(next);
    counter = counter+showitems;
    if (counter>=$scope.total_invoice_records.length) {
      $scope.noMoreItemsAvailable = true;
    }
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
  };
```

Most importantly, remember to set the immediate-check attribute on the infinite scroll element to **false**:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore()" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: ys ..i got it your answer is perfect ..but there might be one case when user load all data after scrolling down down and load 5000 object .mean he will able to see all object in that container .In that time is application slow ? because I thing 5000 element or object in dom ..?

Comment: I think this solution .But there might be a better solution..I think better solution may be this if I take three or 3 divs .example "top" ,"middle", "bottom".Load "100" object in middle div .if user move bottom of "middle" div I swap the middle div content to top div and get new contend in "middle" div .so user user see at most 200 element maximum ..same when user scroll top of "middle" div  middle div contend move to bottom div get new contend on middle div.

Comment: I am thinking may be this is not possible .But I thing this is better solution because in DOM  only at most 200  element present not more that .so our application run fast in any case

Comment: I would test before optimizing.  In any case, you can remove elements by just adjusting the slice on the array.  The first value is where the array will start, so if you want to do some calculations to say never load more than 500 rows or something you could easily do that, but remember, you'll need to create your own directive to handle reloading the elements when the user scrolls up.  Like I said: always test before optimizing.

Comment: could you please look this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679783/why-after-loading-more-data-filter-stop-working

Comment: pls looks this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679783/why-after-loading-more-data-filter-stop-working

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a pagination rather than use infinite scroll; or keep the functionnality of infinite scroll as is.

but if you wish to still use infinite scroll, then when you load your next datas into `_list`, just before filling in the new elements, clean your `_list` with a `_list.length= 0`

But you will have sideeffects that I don't know such as : 
- how to load the 100 first elements ? 
- the page will jump from full with 100 elements, cleaned to 0, and filled with next 100. This will lead, I assume, to an unpleasant effect

My configuration of ion-infinite is the following :

```
  <ion-infinite-scroll     
    ng-if="!myModel.maxItemLoaded"
    icon="ion-loading-c"
    on-infinite="loadMoreData()"
    distance="10"
  >
```

Which means :
- when user scroll gets on the 10 last % of the page height, loads `loadMoreData`

If user never scoll, then he has only the first data shown.

Edit:
Here is an updated plunkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/B5KCbc8hr66upCXMvXSR?p=preview

Few remarks :
- the infinite scroll directive is independent and shall not surroung your table
- accessing to to index is done by $index, not with 'index'
- the load functionnality has been modified to load the next 100 elements

```
$scope.populateList = function() {
        var size = $scope._list.length;
        var maxSize = size + 100;
        if (maxSize > $scope.invoice_records.length)
          maxSize = $scope.invoice_records;
          console.log("populateList",size,maxSize,$scope.invoice_records)
        for (var i = size; i <= maxSize; i++) {
          console.log("push",$scope.invoice_records[i])
          $scope._list.push($scope.invoice_records[i]);
        }    
        console.log($scope._list.length);
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');    
      }
```

Comment: what is best way to load solve this problem when data is large

Comment: can we load data slowly slowly on browser like first 100 then another 100 then again 100 like ...when user to scroll to bottom I added 100 more element is it better way ?

Comment: this is what does ion-infinite scroll. Loads data when you are close to "bottom" of box . I add mine as edit.

Comment: so what is the better solution ?could you help me loading the data using infinite scroll ..could you check my second plunker where I am doing wroong

Answer (score 0):

Angular should work with 5000 object, if it is read only , you can use [one time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)

> An expression that starts with :: is considered a one-time expression.
>   One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable,
>   which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a
>   non-undefined value (see value stabilization algorithm below).

`<span ng-bind="::name"></span>`

---

I don't know infinite scrolling, but if I had to implement something like that i would have used `ng-filter` 'limit'.

```
ng-repeat="column in _list | limit : limitValue"
```

And then bind any button/scroll event to

```
$scope.limitValue = $scope.limitValue + "10";
```

---

Comment: if I give 100 limit then how I will show other 1950 object.i need to show all objects

Comment: I think you didn't give correct answer .Actually I need user scroll the contend then more element is loaded as in ng-infinite scroll

Comment: I never used infinite scroll but, if you bind limit to $scope.limit and then (when you need more elements) you could increase this value by 100 ?

Comment: when user move to bottom of table or in other word move to last or second last row.First check my both plunker then see my problem of hanging UI ..

Comment: Both plunkers are in "infinite loading" state on my side

Comment: wait checking ..Please firest one will show data after few seconds

Comment: First one will show you data after 10 seconds after hanging loader .But second one not because second one I try to implement infinite scrolling

Comment: Without infinite scroll i would use my own filter to limit number of displayed element. (+ one time binding). But the infinite scroll brings scrolling behaviour you probably need. Wait for another SO answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should not have brought this much data in 1 call. Now, if you have, you can achieve this by a small tweak.

Break your data in chunk of 100. And set that 100 in $scope.

```
var brokenData = [];
var totalData = x; // Total 5000 records
var pages = parseInt(totalData.length/100);
if(totalData.length % 100 !== 0) {
    pages += 1;
}
for (var i = 0; i < pages; i++){
    if(i == pages - 1) {
        brokenData.push(totalData);
    } else {
        brokenData.push(totalData.splice(0,100));
    }
}
```

Now set

```
$scope.pages = pages;
```

And for 1st page or for 1st time,

```
$scope.pageData = brokenData[0];
$scope.currentPage = 0 + 1;
```

This will show only 100 records on your page and sets current page as 1.

Now you can choose any pagination tool or bind window scroll events and just update the above 2 things

Like for 2nd page

```
$scope.pageData = brokenData[1];
$scope.currentPage = 1 + 1;
```

Comment: could you please give plunker

Comment: Sure why not. Give me few mins

Comment: No sorry I am not looking for that