# how to display sorted only 25 element in infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using infinite scroll in my demo ,In which I am showing only 25 element first time .When user scroll down to bottom it load more data and display that more data .It is do repeat steps if user want whole data to display (scroll to bottom load more data).but in my demo there is ascending and descending functionality present .On header there is "V" and "^" Button present .using click of that button I need to ascend and descend data .In my demo it is working fine .But the issue is when user click it load all data but I want it show only 25 data (ascending and descending.)

I will explain more .

- When you run app it show only 25 elements in table if user want to see more it scroll the table it load more data when it move to bottom.
- when user Click header left icon (**Account**)"V"  and "^" **Account** .It sorted all the object and display it in screen .All object mean it show 2000 objects in sorted way .
- So the issue is when user click header left icon (**Account**)"V"  and "^" I want to display only 25 element of sorted array and load data when user scroll to bottom .

**HTML**

```
<ion-scroll scrollbar-y="true" ng-style="backGroundImageHeightObj" delegate-handle="invoicegrid">
          <div class="row" ng-repeat="column in invoice_records | orderBy: sortval: reverse track by $index">
            <div class="col col-center brd collapse-sm" ng-repeat="field in column.columns" ng-show="data[$index].checked && data[$index].fieldNameOrPath===field.fieldNameOrPath">{{field.value}}</div>
            <div class="col col-10 text-center brd collapse-sm"></div>
          </div>
        </ion-scroll>
        <ion-infinite-scroll immediate-check="false" ng-if="!noMoreItemsAvailable" on-infinite="loadMore(query)" distance="10%"></ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `ShowViewAfterSuccess` function you slice all invoice records to get just the ones to be displayed:

```
$scope.invoice_records = $scope.total_invoice_records.slice(0, showitems);
```

Then, in the `setSort` function you clear the `invoice_records` list and then set it with the whole list of invoice records (without slicing the first 25):

```
$scope.invoice_records=$scope.total_invoice_records;
```

That's why you get the whole list upon re-sorting.

Ideally, you'd want to get sorted data from the back-end in batches to feed the infinite scroll. Assuming you cannot do that, you can use the limitTo filter to control how many lines are displayed in the ngRepeat. Also, in your `setSort` you may want to scroll back to the top.

Here's an [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fZCSItChxq63zBPSk747?p=info).

Main changes are:

- Added limitTo: counter to the main ngRepeat:

`ng-repeat="column in total_invoice_records | orderBy: sortval: reverse | limitTo: counter track by $index"`

- Made counter a scope variable
- Made sure `$scope.invoice_records` always contains all records by removing all slicing.

Comment: Thanks for replay could you please give plunnker .Actually The reason is why I use this $scope.invoice_records=$scope.total_invoice_records; to sort the all objects

Comment: I used this first I need to sort all objects $scope.invoice_records=$scope.total_invoice_records; ,Then display only 25 objects

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do now. Updated my answer.

Comment: I think that is correct anwser .Please tell me what you do

Comment: I added a description of the code changes in the answer.

Comment: @PallaviSharma  This answer is correct and you should select it as the proper answer to your question, but you should look at the integrated Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/eoDQK5VHDtDjiqnSbChJ?p=preview for the complete solution with scroll, sort and search working together.

Comment: @jme11 please check your this output click on second column"Account ^" and you plunker .it is not match.This answer is correct.because it sort first 2000 objects and then display  only 25 .You only sort 25 object which is display on view .could you please integrate it on your answer

Comment: please take a look on that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30736293/how-to-display-sorted-data-from-complete-object-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment49529089_30736293